# Baby screams while sleeping

Tags: newborn, night-time, night-terrors

We have a baby who is 3 weeks old (when I write this). She is very nice and sleeps very well during the day, however it seems to be difficult for her during the night. The problem is that, even she is sleeping, she makes some noise as if she had nightmares. (This happens each 1 hour during the night.) When we try to hold her and swing her, she becomes calm as usual, but when we put her back to her bed, she feels angry and does not want to sleep anymore.

Someone can help us? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is just a difficult time and she is getting used to be separate from her mother (after all she has been with you her whole life) now she must learn to be separate. I think babies learn very quickly that if they cry they get comfort, and so if she is crying at night repeatedly then perhaps she has already learned this ;)

I don't think crying overall is a bad thing unless there is clearly a problem (illness, rash, etc).

1. Have you tried swaddling blankets at night? (so she feels like she
   is held)
2. Does she sleep in her basket in your bedroom? (so she does not feel
   too far away)
3. Have you tried to comfort her without lifting her out?
4. Is she just hungry?
5. Is it too quiet at night? (maybe she sleeps well in the day because she subconsciously knows that you are close)

I think there are so many reason she might cry, it would be difficult to give just one direct answer, but hopefully some of the above suggestion can help.

Edit: what is the room temperature? Is it too hot or cold?